# javascript execution synchronization at UIWebView

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

I want to change properties (such as `-webkit-text-size-adjust:`,
`-webkit-column-gap`, `-webkit-column-width`, etc) of the WebView Page at `webViewDidFisnishLoad: deligate`, using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, however it works only about half the time.
Sometimes I get a white blank screen(?) or size, column change is not done.

I believe that javascript is not executed properly if/when a touch action occurs or other function is executed while being executed.

I'd like to know if there is a way to check to see changes using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` is properly done or not.
Now I am running `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` by mainthread.